# behaviour of back-button same as behaviour of menu button

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Can I overwrite the behaviour of the back-button so that it becomes the same as the behaviour of the menu button?

```
             document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
                        theSameAsMenuButton();
                    }, false);
```

what must `theSameAsMenuButton`  look like?

With 'menu button' I mean the central button with a shape on it that looks like a house ('home button' ?). Not sure if thats the right nomenclature

Comment: whoever solves that gets rewarded with a 50rs bounty on one of my other questions which is pretty similar.

Comment: Are you looking for it to close the application? or is there something else that button does that you want the back button to do?

Comment: to close the application in the same way that the application closes when the home button is pressed - which is not the same as the normal behaviour of the back-button.